# Difference between GetLastCheckpointRequest and GetAllMutationTokensRequest?

Tags: couchbase, couchbase-java-api

What is difference in sequence number returned by above two ?
AFAIK both return latest sequence number, which might not have been replicated or persisted to disk.

Difference I am aware of,

GetAllMutationTokensRequest returns values only for a single node.
So calling it once for each node should be equivalent to GetLastCheckpointRequest.

GetLastCheckpointRequest returns 1 if no changes, GetAllMutationTokensRequest returns 0.

We use getCurrentState as shown in https://forums.couchbase.com/t/getallmutationtokensrequest-generates-incomplete-response/8166/2.
For clusters which have failed over and rebalanced couple of times, it seems getCurrentState returns no changes from last call, even when there are changes. Earlier we used GetAllMutationTokensRequest, and it returned proper high sequence number.
We are using core-io 1.2.8 .

Answer (score 1):

After this fix https://github.com/couchbase/couchbase-jvm-core/commit/5953dc39d0c212109d951822497ea8d6bf3a4762 `GetAllMutationTokensRequest` properly broadcasted for every node, previous behaviour was due to the bug.

`GetLastCheckpointRequest` is different a bit, because it does not return the current sequence number, but rather seqno of last *closed checkpoint*, which might be different than the value returned by `GetAllMutationTokensRequest`

Comment: Does closed checkpoint mean sequence number which has been persisted and replicated?